# c# two string arrays print first array value to second array value expect 0

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I want the output like this :

```
A=1
C=3
D=9
e=5
```

If second array value is 0 I don't want that value how to achieve this output in c#?

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] a = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" ,"e"};
    string[] b = new string[] {1,0,3,0,5 };

    foreach (string tmp in a)
    {
        bool existsInB = false;
        foreach (string tmp2 in b)
        {
             if (tmp == tmp2)
             {
                 existsInB = true;
                 break;
             }
         }

         if (!existsInB)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} is not in b", tmp));
         }
     }

     Console.ReadLine();
}
```

In that two arrays I want to print values like `a=1,c=3,e=5`, I don't want to print second array zero value. How do I achieve this?

I need a output in c#: `a=1 c=3 e=5`

Answer (score 3):

I believe this will work for you

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] a = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
        int[] b = new int[] { 1, 0, 3, 0, 5 };

        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            if (b[i] != 0)
                Console.WriteLine(a[i] + "=" + b[i]);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Dictionary version (as per Matt Murdock's suggestion):

```
        Dictionary<string, int> ab = new Dictionary<string, int>
        {
            {"a", 1},
            {"b", 0},
            {"c", 3},
            {"d", 0},
            {"e", 5}
        };

        foreach(var pair in ab)
        {
            if(pair.Value != 0)
                Console.WriteLine(pair.Key + "=" + pair.Value);
        }
```

Comment: To make it more dynamic, I think you can replace the loop count with no. of elements in the array.

Comment: You are right. But if it is me I will use a Dictionary. :)

Comment: Better choice, Yes. You can recommend it in your answer too. Its always good to represent optimal ways of solving a problem rather than taken approach and leave the choice to the OP.

Comment: it will print only a=1 , i want to print all values like, a=1,c=3,e=5

Comment: @kavitha I edited my code to include my entire code. Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

The other answer by @interceptwind has already given a solution, this is just an alternative solution with `Linq`

```
string[] a = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
string[] b = new string[] { "1", "0", "3", "9", "5" };

var result = a.Zip(b, (strA, strB) => string.Format("{0}={1}", strA.ToUpper(), strB))
                .Where(s => !s.Contains("=0"))
                .ToArray();
```

Comment: i replace the loop count but i will get only a=1

Comment: please suggest me how to get a=1,c=3,d=9,e=5 using for loop i want to achieve this output.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by *"i replace the loop count"*. Just copy paste this *exact* code and run, you'll get your desired result.

Comment: @KAvitha is interceptwind solution didn't work for you?

Comment: string[] a = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
        int[] b = new int[] { 1, 0, 3, 0, 5 }; //Changed to int

        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            if(b[i] != 0)
                Console.WriteLine(a[i] + "=" + b[i]);
        }   just i copy paste this code the output is came A=1. But i want to print  c=3,d=9,e=5

Comment: It's not working for you? Arghya solution also work for you. What you are trying to say?

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience first answer i copy paste but the output is a=1 other values are not came.how i can achieve this.

Comment: Did you run till the complete loop executed? You didn't stop in-between? Try this code as well, you'll get desired result. But, notice it doesn't print the result.

Comment: it doesn't print the result only first value will be printed (a=1)

Comment: @kavitha I tried the code it print the expected output. I think you doing something wrong.

Comment: no i copy paste the same code i will take a screenshot but i can't paste it here.{"a","b","c"}, {0,1,2} output came for me only first value b=1,but i can't get c=2 is not printed.

Comment: @kavitha you are welcome :) I hope you found out what you did wrong and learned something new.